# Unable to install Dart 2.7.2

Tags: dart, homebrew

I'm trying to install Dart 2.7.2.

Initially I tried to install via:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/fed6de080aef54c4f1c1df732424df37cd3e5a3e/dart.rb
```

Which gives an error:

```
Calling Installation of dart from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract dart' to stable tap on GitHub instead.
```

Next approach, I downloaded the file at:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/fed6de080aef54c4f1c1df732424df37cd3e5a3e/dart.rb
```

And then updated DEVEL block to HEAD block, then ran:

```
brew install --build-from-source ./dart.rb
```

And now I'm getting this error:

```
Error: invalid attribute for formula 'dart': version ("")
```

And I've no idea what to do now...or how to go from here. Any tips?

Comment: Unless you have to use homebrew you could just download the zipped sdk: https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive